# Laravel 4.1 - $user->roles()->detach() issue in testing environment

Tags: php, mysql, testing, laravel

I have tables 'users', 'roles', and 'users_roles'. When I $user->roles()->attach() and detach() it works fine in my local environment with MySQL. But when I try to do the same in my testing environment (memory / Sqlite) $user->roles()-detach() does not work. No errors are thrown, it just doesn't remove the entries from the pivot table. It's like it's not firing or something.

I'm using PHPUnit 3.7

```
$this->roles()->attach(1);
$count = $this->roles->count();
$this->roles()->detach();
```

I've also tried $this->roles()->detach(1) with no luck. Any ideas?

--- Update ---

Something I forgot to mention is that I am running a

```
$count1 = $user->roles->count();
```

between the attach() and detach() and this is what seems to be causing the issue. Why would running a count() between  an attach() and detach() cause detach to not fire? I updated the code above to reflect my new findings.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. Instead of running $user->roles->count() I switched that to be         $count1 = count(User::find($user->id)->roles->toArray());

Seems to be working fine although I don't know if there are any repercussions of that.